# Clarification on saving and retrieving images in android

Tags: android

I am new to android programming.My aim is to save the captured image and to retrieve it when ever user wants.I am stuck with this problem of my project.
The problem is how to write a code if i don't have external memory card in android phone.I googled some sites and wrote something like this.Don't know this is correct or not.I hope i will get a help.

```
public void takephoto1(){ 
        Intent i=new Intent();
        i.setAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File dir= Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);

        output=new File(dir, "firstphoto.jpg");
        i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(output));
        startActivityForResult(i,q);

    }


    public void onActivityResult(int requestcode ,int resultcode,Intent data){
     if(requestcode==q && resultcode==RESULT_OK){
         Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
         i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(output), "image/jpeg");
         Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
         Bitmap  photo = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
         image.setImageBitmap(photo);
         startActivity(i);
         finish();
     }

    }
```

Comment: didn't it worked?

Comment: yes it didnt worked

Answer (score 0):

Just Do it like this

```
 Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
 startActivityForResult(cameraIntent,2);
```

and then

```
     @Override
      protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
       ivCrop.setImageBitmap(scaledBitmap);
}
```

Comment: My code was working but here i am using Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM); for storing an image in android phone but my goal is save a image even if i dont have a sd card in phone.

Comment: I am using a android based phone which don't have a sd card in it. what i am trying to solve is i need to take a photo using camera content(that i got) and save it in a separate folder in gallery and retrieve it back when ever i wanted and display it on Imageview. I hope you understood my question

Answer (score 0):

```
 Intent cameraIntent = new  Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    //cameraIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            "MyPhoto.jpg");
    outPutfileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outPutfileUri);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 2);

   and in onActivityRewsult use

                   File imgFile = new  File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"MyPhoto.jpg");
                Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
                ivCrop.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
```

Comment: what is ivCrop here ? @ Neh kumari

Comment: it is my ImageView name